# How do you "view source" for the "description" in an ebay page?

Tags: html

I am attempting to see how other ebay users construct their descriptions, and as far as I can tell, the description part of the listing page does not show up in the "view source" of any listing page.

So, I figured it was loaded with javascript and used the "view generated source" of the Developer Toolbar addon for FireFox, and still no dice!

Crazy! How I am **not** seeing the page source for the listing descriptions?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) add-on for firefox.

It's got a great DOM inspector that lets you view the source by selecting areas on the rendered page.

Comment: Hah... I have firebug installed, but never used to actually inspect the DOM using the HTML "folder." Thanks... this was the best answer as it really opened my eyes to another amazingly powerful aspect of firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Select description and go for "View Selection Source" option in context menu (right mouse button) in firefox.
It will work even if content is loaded through javascript and very useful when DOM tree is big.

Comment: Ah... very nice, I was trying this as well, but without selecting anything. It gave spurious results.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can right-click on the relevant area of the page and select "View Frame Source". That works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox > ebay.com > Right click on white space > View Page Info, all meta tags shown.

Comment: http://pokit.etf.ba/upload/pokit6aca97005c68f1206823815f66102863.png